# Weird Error JAVA process execution

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [run shell command from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460297/run-shell-command-from-java)

I'm trying to run a process with some arguments from inside Java and before running the particular command I print it using `println`.

Now the problem is from inside Java, the process is not doing good.. its sending some error on the Error Stream instead of output. But If I run the same command printed by Java on screen in console, it works perfectly.

```
String command="abc -def -hhij";
System.out.println(command);
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(command);
```

Anyone know whats going on wrong?

Comment: What error? Could it be an environment variable issue? What happens if you try a simple command like `pwd`?

Comment: I think something went wrong. What went wrong?

Comment: @Shakedown- Added more detail about what went wrong..  ;)

Comment: "Syntax error: ( unexpected". What parameters are you really using? Something probably needs to be escaped or quoted.

Comment: @Thilo- The command with parameters as printed by JAVA is in the question and running this in console works. Also I'm printing using `println()` passing it the string properly escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Runtime.exec(String) using the StringTokenizer, which doesn't know how to process quoted text.  The simplest fix is to use the exec that accepts your parameters in an array.

```
String[] command={ "abc", "-def", "-hhij"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(command);
```

Comment: @phatfingers- I have added the output from ErrorStream in question..

Comment: Try the form of exec that takes a String[] with each parameter as a separate String.  Omit the quotes.

Comment: @phatfingers- Tried that.. still giving the same error.

Comment: Are the parentheses in "likes(john, marry)." the only parentheses in the statement, or are you substituting "[sample]." for some additional data not shown?

Comment: @pathfingers- It worked man... as you shown in answer. Previously, I modified it a little to invlude `"` in args, but that was not right.

Comment: Glad you're back in business!

Answer (score 1):

I would try just to escape those '(' with \: '\\(' (double \ due to Java escaping rules)

Comment: When I try to do that.. it says "Invalid escape sequence"

Comment: @Buxme - You need to escape the `\` in Java: `"...\\\(` will put `\(` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the command needs the full path to the command. C:\dir\abc.exe or whatever.

If it's a script make sure it' executed by the correct shell.