# Restart apache server from java code?

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee

I'd like to execute a apache server restart from within java webapp (restart button or likewise). eg `apachectl graceful`

How could I do this, if ever?

Comment: Just run a shell command, here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460297/run-shell-command-from-java

Comment: Is the Apache server running on the same machine as the Java web app?

Comment: yes it is on the same machine. at least atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the apache server start command in a script and then invoke the script from your Java code.